# Show the next inequality

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Show that:
$$
\frac{3}{8}\leq \int_{0}^{1/2}\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}dx\leq \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}.
$$
I have
$$m(b-a)\leq\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx\leq M(b-a),$$
but the function does not present critical points in its derivative.

And how can I show the following?
$$\frac{|a+b|-|a-b|}{ab}=\frac{2}{\max\{|a|,|b|\}}$$

Comment: Have you mistyped it? Otherwise, I don't understand why the 1+2 in the denominator isn't simplified to 3.

Comment: I' sorry...It is done

Comment: This is be done by observing the [concavity of the integrand](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xips1gz9vs), the slope of tangent at $x=0$, and slope of secant on $[0,1/2]$.  Then calculate the area of trapezoid to finish the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, there seems to be some typing mistake.

For the second, presume that $\left|\frac{b}{a}\right| \le 1$. Then
$$\frac{|a+b|-|a-b|}{ab}=\frac{|a||1+b/a|-|a||1-b/a|}{ab} = |a|\frac{1+b/a-1+b/a}{ab}=\frac{2|a|}{a^2}=\frac{2}{|a|}.$$
Can you figure out what happens when $\left|\frac{a}{b}\right| \le 1$?

Comment: If I also think that, because the minimum and maximum I get other values. Maybe suggestion to show the error?

Comment: +1: I hope you can soon become a 10k user.

Answer (score -1):

If you have
written it correctly,
$\frac{3}{8}
\leq \int_{0}^{1/2}\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+2}}dx
\leq \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}
$
is the same as
$\frac{3}{8}\sqrt{3}
\leq \int_{0}^{1/2}\sqrt{1-x}dx
\leq \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\sqrt{3}
$
or
$\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{8}
\leq \int_{0}^{1/2}\sqrt{1-x}dx
\leq \frac{3}{4}
$.

$\sqrt{1-x}$
is monotonic decreasing,
so,
on $[0, \frac12]$,
$1 \ge \sqrt{1-x} \ge \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.
Therefore
$\frac1{2\sqrt{3}}
\approx 0.2886
\geq \int_{0}^{1/2}\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+2}}dx
\geq \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4\sqrt{3}}
\approx 0.20412
$.

If the denominator
is actually $x+2$,
then
$\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{x+2}}
$
is again monotonic decreasing
so,
on $[0, \frac12]$,
$\sqrt{\frac12}
\ge\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{x+2}}
\ge \sqrt{\frac{\frac12}{\frac52}}
= \sqrt{\frac15}
$
so the integral
is within half of these bounds.

For the second question,
use
$\min(a, b)
=\frac12(|a+b|-|a-b|)
$
and
$\max(a, b)\min(a, b)
=ab
$.

Comment: $$\int_0^{.5}\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{3}}dx \approx 0.24881 < \frac38$$

Comment: Please correct your post, especially the line $$\frac12
\geq \int_{0}^{1/2}\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+2}}dx\geq \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}$$ because [$\int_0^{1/2}\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{3}}dx \approx 0.24881 < \frac38$ and $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4} \approx 0.353553$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=compare+int+sqrt%5B(1-x)%2F3%5D+from+0+to+1%2F2+and+sqrt(2)%2F4).

Comment: I forgot about the $\sqrt{3}$. Don't understand why it is there anyway.

Comment: The very first inequality of your answer is still incorrect as shown in my first comment.  Please change the integrand according to OP's question.  You may find a guide to the solution from my comment to the question.  It provides a graph to the problem, and it should greatly help you to solve the first question.  Please kindly [edit] correct your mistakes or remove your answer.  Until that, -1.

Comment: Not now it isn't.